# Symfony / Apache2 / PHP-FPM 7.3 - net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) in homepage only

Tags: php, symfony, google-chrome, routes, apache2

Tried to look for an answer for two days now. Nothing seems to apply.

- The error `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)` appears in Chrome console.
- If I try to view the page source in browser it looks empty.
- On Firefox there is no error and the page source looks good (the final `</html>` tag is present)
- The error is printed only in homepage and only on server, not locally.
- The page content seems alright, I tested with another's page content (static, no vars) that works fine on another route and the error is still there.
- I've changed the route from `stage.myproject.url` to `stage.myproject.url/x` and the error is not there anymore, so it's pretty much connected to the main URL.

The Apache config looks like this, according to [Symfony Docs: Configuring a Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) and website's needs:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName stage.myproject.url

    DocumentRoot /var/www/stage.myproject.url/public
    <Directory /var/www/stage.myproject.url/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted

        FallbackResource /index.php

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user

    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/stage.myproject.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/stage.myproject.access.log combined


    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.myproject.url/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.myproject.url/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.myproject.url/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any hints on what should I try next?

**Edit**: Disabling the

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

line removes the error and also breaks the Symfony Debug Toolbar.

Comment: Did you check this resource from the Symfony documentation? It's always useful for the server configuration with Symfony : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Yes, the configuration was created following the Symfony docs. Only added a few more lines required by this specific project. I have updated the question with this information. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug in Apache, [fixed in 2.4.25](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58292). The server had Ubuntu 16.04 which has [Apache 2.4.18](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apache2)

To fix it I upgraded Apache from PPA, like so:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
apt-get update
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It has to do with Symfony profiler but I have no clue.

Comment: Yes, in Symfony context it happens when the profiler kicks in. The bug is described at my first link as: "If FallbackResource is executed on a subrequest, the server never sends a last-chunk causing the appearance of a hang in some clients." With Symfony, the profiler uses a subrequest. If upgrading Apache's version did not fixed it, maybe it's something else. Another way to test if it's this bug, is trying to disable the `FallbackResource` directive in your Apache config. If it fixes the problem, then it might be this bug, if not, it might be something else.

Comment: I fixed it: see my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding `DirectoryIndex` before `FallbackResource` for the same index file:

```
    <Directory /var/www/my-app/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        DirectoryIndex /index.php
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to test and confirm your fix since I have already upgraded Apache on that server :)